# How to edit the Date Created value that appears on the Entry page

Tags: control-panel, database, datetime

I've just noticed that there's a Date Created value that appears for each entry in the control panel. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

How can I edit this Date Created value?

I've just looked at the `craft_entries` table and edited the `dateCreated` value for the entry in question, but when I refreshed the entry in the control panel, the Date Created value remained as it was previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to edit that value in the database, then you'll need to find the corresponding row in the `craft_elements` table and update the `dateCreated` column there.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Should I edit the value in craft_elements as well as the value in craft_entries? Or instead of the value in craft_entries?

Comment: Depends on how OCD you are. :)

Comment: Very, or I wouldn't have posted this thread in the first place I guess! :-) I'll do both then. By the way, the reason I want to edit this date is because the homepage entry in my standard build never gets deleted/re-created, so I didn't want client sites to have a Date Created date that was 2 years before I'd even built the site in case they thought it was strange.